# How to Handle (Java-)Script Variables in Python?

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

This opens a new tab in Firefox browser:

```
from selenium import webdriver
browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.execute_script('''window.open("https://www.google.com/","_blank");''')
```

As a reference, here is the [Selenium documentation:](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html)

> `**execute_script**(script, *args)`
> Synchronously Executes JavaScript in the current window/frame.
> **Args**:
> `script`: The JavaScript to execute.
> `*args`: Any applicable arguments for your >JavaScript.
> **Usage**:
> driver.execute_script(‘return document.title;’)

I have a link in a `String` which I wish to open in a new tab using javascript (via `execute_script`).

Tried the following but it gives an error:

```
link = 'https://www.bing.com/'
java_script = '\'\'\'window.open(\"' + link + '\",\"_blank\");\'\'\''
browser.execute_script(script)
```

Error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.JavascriptException: Message: SyntaxError: unexpected token: string literal
```

Comment: use r"string" or """string""" and just don't escape anything

Comment: and to handle variables, execute say "let x = 2; return 2;" and capture this in a python variable, it will work

Comment: Check out f string, there are well suited for the case where you want to put a variable in the middle of a string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

F-string are well suited for that [check them out](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/#simple-syntax)

This will change your code to look like this:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
browser = webdriver.Firefox()
link = 'https://www.bing.com/'
browser.execute_script(f"window.open('{link}','_blank');")
```

Comment: If you add single quotation marks around the curly brackets like `(f"window.open('{link}','_blank');")` it works as wished. Thanks for helping!

Comment: Cool! I'll add it to the answer